# Cannot access a protected member control.CreateHandle()

Tags: c#, user-interface, controls, invoke

I am trying to force to CreateHandles on ***ALL*** controls on the form that has not done that when starting the application.

I am doing that because I use the invoke method to add data to UI controls and I get error messages that no Handle has been created for the control. So I am thinking of doing a security check when starting the application and CreateHandles before running any other code.

However I do get this error message from the below code. In a way I understand the concept of the error message but doesn't know how to change/add any code for this so I can access the control?

```
control.CreateHandle();
```

> Cannot access a protected member control.CreateHandle() via a qualifier of type 'Control'; the qualifier must be of type 'Form1' (orderived from it)

Complete code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => EnumerateChildren(this)); thread.IsBackground = true; thread.Start();
}
public void EnumerateChildren(Control root)
{
    foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
    {
        if (control.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            //Handle is already created
        }
        else
        {
            //Force to Create a handle but gives this error:
            //Cannot access a protected member control.CreateHandle() via a qualifier of type 'Control'; the qualifier must be of type 'Form1' (orderived from it)
            control.CreateHandle();
        }
        if (control.Controls != null)
        {
            EnumerateChildren(control);
        }
    }
}
```

I tested to add the below code in the "else" statment where the second messagebox should show "True" but that doesn't always happen either?

```
else
{
    //Force to Create a handle but gives this error:
    //Cannot access a protected member control.CreateHandle() via a qualifier of type 'Control'; the qualifier must be of type 'Form1' (orderived from it)
    MessageBox.Show("Handle is not created: " + control.IsHandleCreated.ToString());
    control.CreateControl();
    MessageBox.Show("Handle should be created?: " + control.IsHandleCreated.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Reading [the documentation for that method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.createhandle?view=netframework-4.7.2), it says, *"You typically should not call the CreateHandle method directly. The preferred method is to call the CreateControl method, which forces a handle to be created for the control and its child controls when the control is created."*. Are the controls without handles ones you created dynamically?

Comment: @Rufus L, thank you. I red the link. I added/edited some code in my post for the "else" statement where I "CreateControl" and where the second messageBox should show true that a Handle is created. But it mostly show False anyway. One time it did show True though. Why is that?

Comment: @Rufus. All the controls has been added to the form manually(drag and dropped). I do not create any controls dynamically in the code myself.

Comment: Don't use the constructor of your Form.  Use the `Load()` or `Shown()` events...

Comment: @Idle_Mind I did put everything in the Form1_Load event but still I receive the same problem: "Handle should be created?: False"

Answer (score 0):

I did add logic for if CreateControl() doesn't succeed to create a handle. I do createHandle() directly and all controls shows true now which means it seems to work.

Here all controls do get their handle. Please tell if this is a wrong approach?

```
public void EnumerateChildren(Control root)
{
    foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
    {
        if (control.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            //Handle is already created
        }
        else
        {
            control.CreateControl();
            if (control.IsHandleCreated == false)
            {
                //The access the handle directly
                MethodInfo ch = control.GetType().GetMethod("CreateHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                Invoke((System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker)delegate { ch.Invoke(control, new object[0]); });
            }
        }
        if (control.Controls != null)
        {
            EnumerateChildren(control);
        }
    }
}
```